# Allow editors to switch sites (Multisite)

Tags: multisite, capabilities

I have a multisite setup - 2 sites for the same company. Because the sites are for the same company they both share several users with the role 'Editor'.

Is there a way to allow these users to switch between sites in the backend whilst keeping them as Editors? A particular capability I can add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although question is not quite clear to me, because:

## ==case 1==

if you have multisite WP, then users are shared with same username/password/etc). Just you should set the roles individually per sub-site. But if there are many users and you want to automatize the process, you can use:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-sync/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-user-role-sync/
- or some similar alternatives

update: As I see, you only need to "add" (not re-create users, but just "add") into the existing sub-domains. Go to `http://your_site.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, click each listed site individually> go to `Users` tab:

[image]

and insert username (or mail) into `Existing user` > choose Role and click add. (to automatize the work, if there are tens of users and subsites, you can use above plugins.

## ==case 2==

If you have separate installations of WP (and each WP installation is MS itself), then the possible way is like the previous answer suggests (sharing the `user` and `usermeta` tables), but note, there are cases, when in `wp_options` table there could be some information too for specific user, which wont be shared to second site in this case, and you will have to manually share... Not a quite easy trick, but you should live with that.

Comment: It's case 1 - but no users from the first site are present on the 2nd. Also as I said I'm looking for a way for them to switch between the sites using the top admin menu like you can as a network super admin

Comment: @CIvemy yes, it exactly does like you say, they can easily switch the sites.. 
but as i said, you only have to "add" the existing users to those sub-sites. i've updated answer, see it again.

Comment: The point is they can't easily switch sites. They have to go to each wp-admin URL individually. I know existing users can be added to another site in the network, I want them to be able to log in once and use the top menu to switch between sites - exactly as a superadmin does.

Comment: I am surprised - the same navigation top menu should appear for them too, exactly similar as super-admins see (just some sub-buttons wont be available and that's all), otherwise the nav-bar and "Sites" dropdown menu and others, should appear for them too.
Maybe there is something other problem, that interferes to appear that menu? (if a user is added to multi-site, then he doesnt need to login to each site. just one login is enough and they should be auto-logined to all sub-sites). so, something specific problem with your site.

Comment: Are you sure? From what I understand - only superadmins get this menu by default - there is nothing peculiar about the setup of either site or their themes and changing themes makes no difference

Comment: im sure have bing of multiaites, and normal usets have that swiger too, if they are added on multiple sub sites.

Comment: sorry, typing from mobile and misspelled prev.comments. youd better simply create a test user for yourself,assign it editor for multiple sites,then open up private tab in browser(ctrl+shift+n) and login,and see that you will have similar menu

Answer (score 0):

If both sites share all users you could set the second site to use the _users and _usermeta tables from the first site by setting the following constants in the second site:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'yourprefix_1_users');
define('CUSTOM_USERMETA_TABLE', 'yourprefix_1_usermeta');
```

That would also have the advantage of users only needing to manage/remember one set of credentials.